# Bachelor degree in Software engineering in distance (online) in Europe

Tags: education

Currently I wish to expand my professional skills with Bachelor degree. However, I am not able to study full time abroad, but looking for University where I could study in distance (online from home), coming just several times in a semester to the University to pass exams, complete papers and so on.

I am **looking for Software Engineering or Computer Science programs**. **Fully in distance** (online) **in English in Europe**, because I am living in Central Europe.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

You could have a look at the Open University, they have a [European presence](http://www8.open.ac.uk/europe/).  I know that you can certainly complete the bulk of the work online, although I think there are physical attendance requirements for some exams.

Answer (score 0):

I know that it isn't in Europe but the [FAQ page of University of Phoenix](http://www.phoenix.edu/students/faq.html) states that they accept International students for the Online campus which I guess means that there is no physical attendance requirements.